# firebase.messaging.getToken() not working as expected on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, firebase-cloud-messaging, polyfills

I'm trying to ensure that I'll be able to get an fcm device token from firebase whenever I request one via messaging.getToken(). Though I'm having an issue retrieving the token constantly on Google Chrome, it works intermittently.

When I test getting an FCM device token on page refresh on Firefox, it works every single time without fail and I receive a token in my callback function.

On the other hand with Google Chrome, its a completely different story, I only manage to receive a token intermittently. My code stops running at the point where I print in the console "Notification permission granted". No error messages from the catch block.

Upon further investigation, I found that the function messaging.getToken() does not return a token i.e. it was undefined, again, this only happens when I use Google Chrome.

I also tried doing this in a Brave browser, the behavior is similar to that of Google Chrome, except with Google Chrome, when I paste the following code into the console:

```
if(token){
console.log("value of token is:", token)
}
else
{
console.log("value of token is:", token);
}
});
```

it actually prints the token, whereas Brave doesn't.
Then of course IE and Safari don't support Firebase messaging

**Code**

**firebase-init.js:**

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "api-key-here",
     authDomain: "domain-here",
     databaseURL: "data-base-url-here",
     projectId: "project-id",
     storageBucket: "storage-bucket",
     messagingSenderId: "sender-id-here",
     appId: "app-id-here"
 };
 console.log(firebase);
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 
 // Request for permission
         Notification.requestPermission()
             .then((permission) => {
                
                
                 console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                 console.log(permission);
             //code stops running here on google chrome
             messaging.getToken()
                     .then((currentToken) => {
                         if (currentToken) {
                             console.log('Token: ' + currentToken);
                             sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                             var data = { newToken: currentToken };
                             var url = "/Account/UpdateFirebaseToken";
                             $.ajax({
                                 url: url,
                                 type: "POST",
                                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                 dataType: "text",
                                 processData: false,
                                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                 success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                                     console.log("successfully retrieved token:", data, status, jqXHR);
                                 },
                                 error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                                     console.log(err);
                                 },
                                 complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                                     console.log("request complete");
                                 }
                             });
                         } else {
                              //doesn't reach here
                             console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                             setTokenSentToServer(false);
                         }
                     })
                     .catch(function (err) {
                         //doesn't reach here either
                         console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                         setTokenSentToServer(false);
                     });
             })
             .catch(function (err) {
                 console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
             });

    //});
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js:**

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
    apiKey: "api-key-here",
    authDomain: "auth-domain-here",
    messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    var dataFromServer = JSON.parse(payload.data.notification);
    var notificationTitle = dataFromServer.title;
    var notificationOptions = {
        body: dataFromServer.body,
        icon: dataFromServer.icon,
        data: {
            url: dataFromServer.url
        }
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
    var urlToRedirect = event.notification.data.url;
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(urlToRedirect));
});
```

Comment: You have missing returns - `return messaging.getToken()...` and `return $.ajax({...})`. 
Doesn't answer your polyfill issue but may help explain some of the "doesn't reach here" behaviour.

Comment: I'll try adding the return and check if that makes a difference while also keeping the reference to the promise polyfill script?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the following script tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>
```

from my _Layout.cshtml resolved the issue.

I'm not sure how that script is interfering with the promises, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Please guys if I'd really love to know why

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related with IndexedDB (that's where it hangs when debugging 
 the firebase code).

I had the exact same issue you did although I was injecting promise-polyfill through a webpack build. Your post allowed me to fix something that was making me mad for several weeks.

I resolved my particular issue by only applying the polyfill if `window.Promise` was not present so that my code (and the firebase SDK) would use the native Promise.

Comment: I'm glad I could help  , and thank you for the advice, much appreciated.